# prevent specific page from direct Access

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, security, defined

I have a page that I don't want users to access directly for security reasons.

For example I have a page profile.php;  I want when a user presses the button the profile page will open and if he wants to access page directly from url it will restrict him.

```
<?php define('SECURE_PAGE', true);include 'includes/page.php';?>
```

I have tried this but couldn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return `403` status code under certain condition:

```php
if ($something) {
    http_response_code(403);
    // optionally display nice 403 page with `include()` or just `echo`.
    exit;
}
```

Comment: When i put  define a constant in index.php and acces it in profile.php it says undefined constant

Comment: Do you use any framework? The constant itself won't do anything.

Comment: No, actually i am new to php

Comment: Take a look at that suggested answer above. It shows how to do it via .htaccess, however I think in most cases it should be done in the code.